# Use activemailer just for the templates but send using another service?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is it possible for me to somehow use part of active-mailer specifically just the template + model merging portion of it?

I want to do something like this:

```
  html_message = UserMailer.welcome_email(@user).message

  some_api.send_email(from, to, subject, html_message)
```